# How do I get Post/Get Data in Chomium (DCEF3 / Delphi 7)

Tags: delphi, chromium, chromium-embedded

I hope someone can help!

I'm converting a Delphi 7 app that uses TWebBrowser to use Chromium instead.

Something I'm having a problem with, I display the Post/Get values to the user in OnBeforeNavigate2 I grab the PostData and do ByteArrayToStr(PostData,sPostData); to turn it into a readable string.

I've gone through the documentation and found the spec for CefPostData but cannot work out which method to use and how to acccess it.

Does anyone have example code or can steer me in the right direction?

I had a look at a post on StackOverflow that explains how to Send Post data, but I can't find anything for writing it.

Thanks in advance,